# Kafka: Set ACLs for multiple users when zookeeper.set.acl=true?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

My setup is the following:

- 3 Zookeeper nodes secured in the following way:

  - SASL enabled (quorum.auth.enableSasl=true)
  - Requires SASL for learners (learnerRequireSasl=true)
  - Require SASL for servers (quorum.auth.serverRequireSasl=true)
  - Require SASL for clients (requireClientAuthScheme=sasl)
  - A jaas.conf file with the entries QuorumServer, QuorumLearner (both with the same *zookeeper* account and password), and Server (with a *kafka* plus a ***superuser*** account, plus passwords)

The idea of the *superuser* account is that I can use a separate identities and secrets (and possibly permissions) for the Kafka cluster vs. connections by admins from CLI tools.

Then...

- 3 Kafka nodes secured in the following way:

  - All listeners require SASL_PLAINTEXT (listener.security.protocol.map)
  - SASL mechanism is SCRAM-SHA-512 (sasl.enabled.mechanisms)
  - Brokers require SASL for interbroker as well as client connections (sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol)
  - Super users: *kafka*, *superuser*
  - **Set ACLs** on all metadata that Kafka creates (zookeeper.set.acl=true). See (KIP-38)(https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-38%3A+ZooKeeper+Authentication)

In Kafka + Zookeeper deployments with default settings, Zookeeper essentially applies no noteworthy protection mechanisms. Any rogue actor who can connect to a Zookeeper instance (e.g. after penetrating the so-called isolated network) can change Kafka metadata stored in Zookeeper at will, such as creating new Kafka users and elevating permissions.

With the **zookeeper.set.acl=true** setting, Kafka will automatically apply ACLs to all the Znodes it creates (for clusters, topics, offsets, etc.) so that its Znodes are protected from unauthenticated and unauthorized access = more defense in depth.

**Important**: These ACLs are Znode ACLs (a Zookeeper concept) and not the same as the Kafka ACLs that can be applied to clusters, topics, and the like. The *zookeeper-shell.sh* example below shows the subnodes of */config* and the ACL set on the */config/users* Znode. Only the *kafka* identity has full control, *world* has no access whatsoever:

```
ls /config
   [changes, clients, brokers, users, topics]
getAcl /config/users
   'sasl,'kafka
   : cdrwa
```

Kafka will only set ACLs on Znodes for one account, which is typically named *kafka*. Certain Kafka administration tasks, such as adding Kafka users with SCRAM-SHA-512 authentication (kafka-configs.sh tool), cannot be done through Kafka brokers but require direct interaction between the CLI tool and Zookeeper.

And this finally gets me to the problem that I am facing: Because Znode ACLs automatically set by Kafka brokers are only set for the *kafka* identity, it is not possible to perform Zookeeper CLI operations using any other identity, such a *superuser* identity.

**Question**: Does anybody know how to make Kafka set Znode ACLs for more than just the *kafka* identity? Specifically, I would also like the *superuser* identity to be able to make modifications directly in Zookeeper.